# Series of complex Fourier coefficients.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I've been trying to figure this out for days now, but I have no idea how to show this.  It's from *Partial Differential Equations: An Introduction*  by Walter A. Strauss.

Suppose  $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} [ |f(x)|^2 + |g(x)|^2 ] dx $ is finite where $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{e^{ix} - 1}$.  Let $c_n$ be the coefficients of the complex Fourier series of $f(x)$.  Show that $\sum_{-N}^N c_n \rightarrow 0$ as $N \rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = \sum c_n e^{inx}$ and $g(x) = \sum d_n e^{inx}$.  Since $\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(x)|^2 \, dx < \infty$, and $\int_{-\pi}^\pi |g(x)|^2 \, dx < \infty$, by Parseval's identity, we know that $\sum |c_n|^2 < \infty$ and $\sum |d_n|^2 < \infty$.

Also, since $f(x) = g(x)(e^{ix}-1)$, we have $c_n = d_{n-1} - d_{n}$.  Hence
$$ d_{-n} = d_0 - c_0 - c_{-1} - \dots - c_{-n+1} \text{ for $n \ge 0$.}$$
Since $d_{-n}\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, it follows that 
$$ d_0 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_{-k} .$$
Also
$$ d_n = c_n + c_{n-1} + \dots + c_{1} + d_0 .$$
Since  $d_{n}\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, it follows that 
$$ d_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} c_k = 0 .$$

Comment: What does this have to do with $\int_{-\pi}^\pi [|f(x)|^2 + |g(x)|^2] dx$?  Also $f(x) = g(x) (e^{ix} - 1)$ not $g(x)(e^{inx} - 1)$.

Comment: You use the integral with Parseval's Theorem to get the sum of squares formulas.  As for the sign error, I'll fix it, but it won't substantially change the proof.

Comment: Can you show me how you used parsevals for this?

Comment: $$ \frac1{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(x)|^2 \, dx = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty |\hat f_n|^2 $$ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity

Comment: Oops, I had an extra $n$ there.  That was a typo.

Comment: Are you saying that $\int_{-\pi}^\pi [|f(x)|^2 + |g(x)|^2]dx$ being finite implies that $\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(x)|^2 dx$ is finite?

Comment: Yes.  Because $0 \le |f(x)|^2 \le |f(x)|^2 + |g(x)|^2$.

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: Because if $0 \le u(x) \le v(x)$, then $0 \le \int_a^b u(x) \, dx \le \int_a^b v(x) \, dx $.

Comment: 0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{x}, for $0 < x < 1$ but $\int_{0}^1 x dx = 1$ and $\int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{x} dx = \infty$.  Actually just make that 0 < x < 1.

Comment: But, $g(x)$ is undefined at $x = 0$ so it's an improper integral.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't contradict anything I said, because $0 \le 1/2 \le \infty$.  (Typo $\int_0^1 x \, dx = 1/2$.)

Comment: Okay thanks a lot.